# Dynamically updating count using ncurses in PHP

Tags: php, ncurses

Take this PHP script for example:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($arrKey as $VarKey)
{
    $i++
    echo $i;
}
```

I would like to use ncurses to make it dynamically update the echo, so that instead of echoing each time, only the number changes. Problem is, I have no idea how to do this. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you had better read the [PHP ncurses manual](http://php.net/book.ncurses) for starters.

Also found a [reasonable tutorial on the Zend Developer Zone](http://devzone.zend.com/173/using-ncurses-in-php/) regarding the use of the ncurses library, as the PHP manual on it's own does not give a good introduction on how to actually go about using it.

This sort of console manipulation is not for the feint-hearted however.